# Keeping playback buttons layout in iOS 16

Tags: swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, ios16

Does anyone know if it is possible to keep the iOS 15 playback button layout instead of the new iOS 16 layout? (see image attached)

I mean, keeping the compact playback buttons at the bottom of the screen in iOS 16?

[image]

Comment: Hello Luciano Perez,

Did you find any solution ?

Comment: Hi @HardikThakkar, no, I haven't found any solution.

Answer (score 1):

try this one -

```swift
parent.addChild(playerViewController)

container.addSubview(playerViewController.view)
```

Comment: Congrats for your first answer. In the future, try to wrap code within ``` . That way it’s better formatted and easier to read.